# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused when trying to add connect laravel database to Heroku

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, heroku

So I have a site on Heroku, which loads fine as long I don't go to a page that requires a database connection. What happens when I do land on one of those pages, is I get this error:

`PDOException in Connector.php line 55: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`

I'm using [db4free.net](http://db4free.net) to try to access a MySQL database. This is my database.php file. The ****** masking the actual values.

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql-production'),

'mysql-production' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'db4free.net'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'en*******'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', '*******'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '*******'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

This my env file:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:tUWa6AteuAOfEAh/IKx3c13tJEzSmS4La8QdKlEgByQ=
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=enviro-2
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

The env file is ignored by git.

Prior to trying db4free.net I tried following the steps in this article
https://mattstauffer.com/blog/laravel-on-heroku-using-a-postgresql-database/ but I still have the exact same problem. I also set the APP_KEY in the Heroku config variables to match the one in my env file.

Anyone have any ideas on why I get this error?

Comment: Do you have a switch were the programm decides to take local or remote data? Check again your connection data.

Comment: Are you referring to my APP_ENV=local variable in my .env file? It's set to local data.

Comment: I had a similar issue and the same error. It didn pass the correct connection values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your connection details in .env file in incorrect.
you should write your credentials details in .env file as well as database.php file

Comment: I'm a little confused would the incorrect details make a difference when it's uploaded to Heroku's servers? I ask because when I push the master to Heroku, I'm not pushing the .env file.

Comment: env('DB_HOST', 'db4free.net') this line means that read the Host from env file and if it doesnt exist see the next argument.
if nothing helps simply remove env() and write this corresponding to each line 'host' => 'db4free.net' , and so on

Comment: Yeah, this turned out to be the problem. Seems that in my database.php the variables were pointing to the env file I didn't realize that. So I removed env() from any variable using it and that solved it. Thanks